# Can you estimate the difference of primes between numerator and denominator?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, twin-primes

Let $p_n$ the **nth twin prime**, it is $p_n$ is a prime number and $2+p_n$ is also a prime. It is well know that **Brun's theorem** states (unconditionally) that

$$\mathcal{B}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{p_n}+\frac{1}{2+p_n}\right)<\infty,$$
(it is close to $1.9021...$) following a comment in **MathWolrd**, the page dedicated to the  [Brun's constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrunsConstant.html) it expresses the **scarcity of twin primes**.

I think about the following idea, perhaps there is one better than 
the following attempt at exploration of this fact. If this question doesn't capture some of this essence (the exploration of the problem involving twin primes) you are welcome to add a comment.

**We assume that there are infinitely many twin primes,** as hypothesis to work (thus we assume the known asymptotic related in the so called **Twin Prime Conjecture**). For each  integer $N\geq1$ we define the partial sum of previous series as
$$\mathcal{B}_N=\sum_{n= 1}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{p_n}+\frac{1}{2+p_n}\right)=\frac{a_N}{b_N}$$

without a simplification of common factors (this is, in the case that $a_N$ and $b_N$ have common prime factors, we don't simplify these), thus we take $b_N=\prod_{k=1}^Np_k(2+p_k)$, and $a_N$ the corresponding finite series such that $\mathcal{B}_N=a_N/b_N$.

> **Example 1.** As $\mathcal{B}_1=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}=\frac{5+3}{3\cdot5}$, then we take $a_1=8$ and $b_2=15$.
>
> **Example 2. (Update.)** See this technical details in comments, for the first interpretation, 
>   $$\mathcal B_2=\frac13+\frac15+\frac15+\frac17=\frac{5\cdot7+2\cdot3\cdot7+3\cdot5}{3\cdot5‌​\cdot7}.$$

**Important.** Thus we take this interpretation (the first interpretation in comments).

Now we take $N$ large enough to  ensure that $a_N>b_N$ (after the first terms in the sequence $(\mathcal{B}_N)_{N\geq 1}$, we have this assert).

My idea to explore is use the **prime counting function** $\pi(x)$  and ask

> **Question.** When $N\to\infty$, what can you say about an asymptotic for $$\pi(a_N)-\pi(b_N)?$$ I say an asymptotic with an error term (small or big oh)  or well an equivalence $\sim$.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: My only goal is learn and edit nice post in this site. I would to know if  for example this idea captures some fact about twin primes, then I will know if this questions/ideas are partly correct, or they are totally disposable. From my point of view I think, if it isn't in the literature,  that might be interesting to study the convergence/divergence of the series and products involving primes combining with the density of such sequences of primes, in a way like this (I talk from my ignorance), if it is possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "without a simplification of common factors"? For example, $$\mathcal B_2=\frac13+\frac15+\frac15+\frac17=\frac{5\cdot7+2\cdot3\cdot7+3\cdot5}{3\cdot5\cdot7},$$which could give $a_2=92$ and $b_2=105$; or do you calculate it as $$\mathcal B_2=\frac13+\frac15+\frac15+\frac17=\frac{5\cdot5\cdot7+3\cdot5\cdot7+3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7+3 \cdot 5 \cdot5}{3\cdot5\cdot5\cdot7},$$so that $a_2=460$ and $b_2=525$?

Comment: I'm sorry @JohnBentin I was disconnected. I did not think this problem with of the first twin primes , so here  we take the second way that you writes. I hope that my question has mathematical sense. Very thanks much

Comment: I think that you might be better off with the first interpretation, which ensures that $b_N$ is square-free and that all pairs $(a_N,b_N)$ ($N=1,2,...$) are coprime as originally calculated; otherwise, every $(a_N,b_N)$ ($N=2,3,...$) will have an unnecessary common factor $5$. The cost of doing this would be the need to write $b_N$ as $3\prod_{k=2}^Np_k(2+p_k)$. Incidentally, rather than having to type hundreds of capital letters $N$, it would nice to have a lowercase $n$; for summation indices, the letters $i$, $j$, etc. can be used.

Comment: Very thanks much for these details, I've edit the post to improve with your idea @JohnBentin  Thanks and sorry all users.

Comment: If you edit the mathematics according to my suggestions, I will---if you like---do a thorough edit of the English.

Comment: Perfect! Do @John Bentin, Many thanks